# Horizontal Scaling and Design Patterns

Tags: design-patterns, amazon-web-services, horizontal-scaling

I wanted to ask if there are some significant, easy to follow papers or documentation about well known and efficient horizontal scaling patterns. I want to design an application that will be capable of scaling horizontally over the cloud (e.g. on Amazon WS). Is there any design patterns that are accepted by the industry especially from applications that scale automatically (e.g. NoSQL solutions, document databases etc.). One example is the One Master Multiple readers approach of REDIS.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no one silver bullet to handle all kind of cases.That is what makes difficult to come up with a scalable architecture.

Scalable solution can only be created for each case separately. For example in one case you may have so little data but so many requests than external caching can provide great benefit for you as a scalable solution. In another case you may have so many writes and so little reads than you may get benefit of using sharding etc. Even in the cases I mentioned above, the solution I proposed can not be good fit in every specific case. For example sharding have its own problems and caching is a pita if you need fresh data etc.

But of course there are some well-known and proved solutions or recommendations to follow. Like not keeping any state in application if you want to have horizontal scale on application side. Also microservices kind of design pattern you asked for but it is not actually a clear and easy to implement concept.      .